# App is working on Simulator but not on Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have these two errors in my project:

```
Cannot find protocol declaration for 'AppConsentDelegate'
Reference to 'AppConsentDelegate' is ambiguous
```

It's a library from CocoaPods and I don't understand why this is working on Simulator (I tried several ones on 13.5 and 14.4) and not on Device (I tried on 14.4). I can't even archive it.

Clean build and DerivedData folder, quit Xcode, `pod deintegrate`, `pod clean` and `pod install` don't solve the issue.

I'm not very familiar with Objective-C, please help me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you importing that header file and where?

Comment: @cora I added a screenshot in the post. This import is in a file named `App-Swift.h`.